# Вывести результат из 2 массивов

Tags: java, kotlin

не могу решить такую задачу:
у меня есть 2 массива и нужно и нужно каждое число из масива B разделить на число из массива А. если хоть одно число делится без остатка то тогда записать его в начало массива С, а те что не делятся то конце того же массива(без повторения) и по возрастанию.

```
    val a = intArrayOf(9, 7, 5, 3)
    val b = intArrayOf(11, 23, 9, 25, 25, 45, 72)
    val c = mutableSetOf<Int>()
```

Такой должен быть конечный результат:
// result : [9,25,45,72,11,23]

Comment: "не могу решить такую задачу" - как Вы ее решали и не смогли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с использованием Stream API:

- разбить список `b` на две части в зависимости от того, делится ли данное число на любое число, отличное от 0, из `a`, используя `Collectors.partitioningBy()` и `Stream::filter` + `Stream::noneMatch`
- полученную хэш-таблицу отсортировать по ключу (признаку кратности)
- объединить два списка в один `LinkedHashSet`

```java
var a = List.of(9, 7, 5, 3);
var b = List.of(11, 23, 9, 25, 25, 45, 72);
        
Set<Integer> result = b.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
        x -> a.stream().filter(y -> y != 0).noneMatch(y -> x % y == 0)
    )) // false -> имеющие делители в a, true -> без делителей
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // для перестраховки
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()) // общий Stream<Integer> для двух подсписков
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
System.out.println(result);
// -> [9, 25, 45, 72, 11, 23]
```

---

Альтернативное решение с использованием `removeIf, removeAll, addAll`:

```java
var c = new LinkedHashSet<>(b);
var d = new LinkedHashSet<>(b);
// оставить в `c` только числа, имеющие делители
c.removeIf(x -> a.stream().filter(y -> y != 0).noneMatch(y -> x % y == 0));
// убрать из `d` числа, имеющие делители
d.removeAll(c);
// и поместить их в конец множества `c`
c.addAll(d);
System.out.println(c);
// -> [9, 25, 45, 72, 11, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Через цикл можно попробовать. В' индекс проверить не является ли число нулём, затем делить его на А' индекс, проверить является ли полученный результат целочисленным значением, пробежаться по массиву С' в поиске копии и записать при отсутствии